# Vuejs 3 props are undefined inside onMounted

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, vue-props

I have some issue when I want to get some date from the props inside onMounted function.

Main store module:

```js
import { createStore } from 'vuex'
import { categories } from './modules/categories'

export default createStore({
  state: {
  },
  mutations: {
  },
  actions: {
  },
  modules: {
    categories
  }
})
```

I am calling getCategory action every time when I change route.

**categories.js vuex module**

```js
export const categories = {
  namespaced: true,
  state: {
    allCategories: []
  },

  getters: {
    getAllCategories (state) {
      return state.allCategories
    },
  },

  mutations: {
    UPDATE_ALL_CATEGORIES (state, newValue) {
      state.allCategories = newValue
    },
  },

  actions: {
    async getCategories ({ commit, rootGetters }) {
      const accessToken = rootGetters['auth/getAccessToken']

      fetch('http://localhost:8080/api2/getCategories.php', {
        method: 'post',
        headers: { 'Content-type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' },
        withCredentials: true,
        body: JSON.stringify({
          token: accessToken
        })
      }).then(res=>res.json()).then((response) => {
        if (response.status != '200') {
          commit('UPDATE_ALL_CATEGORIES', response)
        }
      }).catch((error) => {
        console.log('Looks like there was a problem: \n', error);
      });
    },
  },

  modules: {
  }
}
```

Categories.vue

```html
<template>
  <div class="page-container">
    <div>
      <div class="items-title">
        <h3>List of categories</h3>
        <span>({{ allCategories.length }})</span>
      </div>
      <div class="items-container">
        <div class="item" v-for="(category, index) in allCategories" :key="index">
          <span class="item-cell size-xs">{{ index + 1 }}.</span>
          <span class="item-cell size-l">{{ category.name }}</span>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <custom-select
      :options="allCategories"
    />
  </div>
  
</template>

<script>
import CustomSelect from '../components/Input/CustomSelect'
import { computed } from 'vue'
import { useStore } from 'vuex'

export default {
  components: {
    CustomSelect
  },

  setup() {
    const store = useStore()

    const allCategories = computed(() => store.getters['categories/getAllCategories'])

    return {
      allCategories
    }
  }
}
</script>

<style lang="scss" scoped>
  @import '@/assets/scss/variables.scss';

</style>
```

In categories component I have imported CustomSelect component. When I want to console log props in onMounted function, props are undefined. Does anyone knows what can be a problem?

**CustomSelect.vue**

```html
<template>
  <div class="custom-select-container" @click="openSelect">
    <div class="selected-item">
      <span class="selected-items-text">{{ selectedItem.name }}</span>
      <span class="icon-arrow1_b selected-items-icon" :class="{ active: showOptions }" />
    </div>
    <transition name="fade">
      <ul v-show="options.length && showOptions" class="custom-select-options">
        <li v-for="(option, index) in options" :key="index" class="custom-select-item" @click="changeSelected(option)">{{ option.name }}</li>
      </ul>
    </transition>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import { ref, onBeforeUpdate, onMounted } from 'vue'

export default {
  props: ['options'],

  setup(props) {
    let showOptions = ref(false)
    let selectedItem = ref({})

    onBeforeUpdate(() => {
      if (Object.keys(selectedItem.value).length === 0) {
        selectedItem.value = props.options[0]
      }
    })
    
    onMounted(() => {
      console.log(props.options[0])
    })

    const openSelect = () => {
      showOptions.value = !showOptions.value  
    }

    const changeSelected = (item) => {
      selectedItem.value = item
    }

    // console.log(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(props.options)))

    return { 
      openSelect,
      showOptions,
      changeSelected,
      selectedItem
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

This whole part in `getCategories` action is really strange:

```js
.then(res=>res.json()).then((response) => {
        if (response.status != '200') {
          commit('UPDATE_ALL_CATEGORIES', response)
        }
      })
```

1. `res.json()` returns just the [body parsed as JSON](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Body/json) so you cannot do `response.status` check against it. If you want to check the status, do it before calling `res.json()`
2. Status check is all wrong. It should use equal `===` and `response.status` is a number ([unsigned short](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Response/status#value)) not a string...

So fix your code, place some `console.log` into an action and mutation and check again...

#### Update

1. Getting `Proxy` when you do `console.log` in Vue 3 is absolutely normal. In order to detect changes to the data Vue wraps the data with [Proxy](https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/reactivity.html#reactivity-in-depth)
2. Getting `undefined` in props

The prop `options` you are passing to your `CustomSelect.vue` is coming from `allCategories` computed which is a `getAllCategories` getter in the store. Getter returns `state.allCategories` which is initially an empty array. Only place where `state.allCategories` is assigned is in the `getCategories` action, which is never executed in the code you posted. And even if it is executed in some code you didn't posted, it is an async call...which means it takes some time to complete and assign the value to `state.allCategories`. It means that almost always when you access `state.allCategories` in `onMounted` of any of your components, it will be an empty array (because `fetch` call is not completed). So `options[0]` when the `options` is empty array will give you `undefined`

Comment: But I think problem is not there. If I do console log inside onBeforeUpdate, I will get data.
If I do inside of onMounted function I will not get data. In response, I have status, that's why I am checking this.

Comment: I don't understand why you talking about `onMounted` all the time. There is no `onMounted` anywhere in the code you posted...

Comment: Ah sorry, I added wrong code. I updated now, and you can see onMounted. I am trying to do console.log(props.options) inside onMounted, and got Proxy {} as a result.

Comment: So there is no possibility to get data onMounted?